# Unipolar op amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, transfer-function

Ex :

[image: circuit]

My question is since it's a single supply op amp, does this mean that we can't generate negative voltage so the transfer function would bottom at 0?

Comment: Assuming that the intersection of the axes in your graphs represents 0 V, and Vcc is not 0 V, and R1 is not infinite, and R2 is not 0 ohms, then neither graph is right.

Comment: yea sorry realized my mistake. I recentered my question about what I am really trying to figure out.

Comment: By the way, the usual term is "single supply" not unipolar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the output will be approximately equal to the negative supply voltage (0 V in this case) when \$v_i < V_{cc}\frac{R2}{R1+R2}\$ and approximately equal to the positive supply voltage when \$v_i > V_{cc}\frac{R2}{R1+R2}\$.

The comparator doesn't know or care whether the negative and positive supply voltages are positive, negative, or equal to the circuit reference (ground) voltage.

Comment: To the OP: some op-amps do a better job than others of driving the output voltage close to the power rail voltages. The term you would be looking for if you want that feature is "rail-to-rail" output.